# Interesting "Hello World" Interview

Tags: python

We have a question we ask at our office during interviews that goes like this.  For the sake of consistency, I am restricting the context of this to python.  I'm sure there are other answers but I'm really only interested in python answers.

Write me a function named `say` that when called like this:

```
>>> say('Hello')('World')
```

It ONLY Prints (not returns):

```
>>> say('Hello')('World')
Hello World
>>>
```

We got into a meta discussion after the interview today where I stated that I am always hoping the applicant will answer with the following.

```
def say(x):
 print "Hello World"
 return lambda a:None
```

I realized that there is a possibility of shortening this further by replacing the `lambda` function with a built in of some sort that returns `None` but I've dug and can't seem to find one that is shorter than `lambda a:None`

So the overall question here is...

Can you think of a way to make this shorter, as in less overall characters (ignoring line breaks).  Any import statements are counted in your character count. (52 Characters)

**UPDATE**

(39 Characters)

```
>>> def p(x):
...  print "Hello",x
>>> say=lambda x:p
>>> say("Hello")("World")
Hello World
>>>
```

Python 3 Answer
(48 Characters)

```
>>> def say(x):
...  return lambda a:print("Hello World")
>>> say("Hello")("World")
Hello World
>>>
```

Comment: do you want `say` to actually use it's arguments? or should it always just `print 'Hello World'`?

Comment: The entire point of the post is he thinks it would be funny if it _didn't_ use its arguments.

Comment: yes, we are ok with something that always prints `"Hello World"` because often when we phrase the question, our language leaves room for this output.

Comment: And what makes this interesting?

Comment: Why is this a good interview question? I'd hope you're not expecting developers to write functions in the form of foo(arg)(arg).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Python 2.x answers**

The obvious answer that doesn't actually count because it returns the string instead of printing it:

```
>>> say = lambda x: lambda y: x + " " + y
>>> say('Hello')('World')
'Hello World'
```

This one is 45 characters counting newlines:

```
def p(x):
 print "Hello World"
say=lambda x:p
```

This method drops it down to 41 characters but it looks kind of odd since it uses one argument but not the other:

```
def p(x):
 print "Hello",x
say=lambda x:p
```

**Python 3.x answers**

36 characters:

```
>>> say=lambda x:lambda y:print(x+" "+y)
>>> say('Hello')('World')
Hello World
```

38 characters:

```
>>> say=lambda x:print(x,end=' ') or print
>>> say('Hello')('World')
Hello World
```

Comment: This returns the argument, it needs to actually print it.  I'll clarify my question.

Comment: Yeah that's basically the answer with which any competent programmer should come up with. I mean who in their right mind would try the above in a serious interview for a job he really, really wanted? Probably depends also on the tone of the interview and I could imagine myself throwing the first one in just for fun before answering it correctly

Comment: @F.J - Sorry to keep respecifying.  The import statements make your character count longer.  I count 76.  I've again re-clarified my question.

Comment: this was fun.  I'll pop back by here later and check for better answers, but for now, you've got it.

Answer (score 7):

```
def say(x):
   print x,
   return say
```

Comment: see the edit I made above.  Yours still returns a function.  Sorry to be so specific.

Answer (score 5):

At least in Python 3, `print` is a function that returns `None`, so you can do this:

```
def say(x):
    return lambda a: print ('Hello World')
```

or (saving a few more characters):

```
say=lambda x:lambda y:print("Hello World")
```

Comment: Oooh.  Sneaky python 3 answer.  I like it!

Answer (score 0):

```
say = lambda y:(lambda x:print(y+' '+x))
say('Hello')('World')
hello world
```

Comment: Actually you have to include `+ ' ' +` as well to separate the words according to OPs question. And if you do you are in direct confict with aleardy given answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7017909/8928024).